# ExpressionEngine and generating PDF issue

Tags: add-on, plugin, pdf-press

I have used PDF Press to generate PDFs from data but somehow generated output is rendered ad text/html not PDF which looks like

> %PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >>
>   endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type
>   /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font <<
>   /F1 8 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] >> endobj 4 0
>   obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (DOMPDF) /CreationDate
>   (D:20140206173022-05'00') /ModDate (D:20140206173022-05'00') >> endobj
>   6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj
>   << /Length 74 >> stream 0.000 0.000 0.000 rg BT 34.016 746.579 Td /F1
>   12.0 Tf [(test 123)] TJ ET endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding
>   /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj xref 0 9 0000000000 65535 f 0000000008
>   00000 n 0000000073 00000 n 0000000119 00000 n 0000000273 00000 n
>   0000000302 00000 n 0000000416 00000 n 0000000479 00000 n 0000000603
>   00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 712
>   %%EOF

I have try to use that plugin http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header but I'm getting same result.

With another test I have run from same hosting simple PHP code to generate PDF using FPDF and I'm able to render PDF.

I don't think this is a Virtuamin or Apache issue - neither would be forcing the HTTP header. More likely the header is being set twice in the script, perhaps once to the default of text/html and then again by add-on to application/pdf and EE force to use text/html

Any clue what can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue related to DOMPDF library used by PDF Press.

I have modified third_party/pdf_press/dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php file based on third_party/pdf_press/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php file. Other way wasn’t working (probably something wrong with absolute path).

Fix above resolved issue with generating PDFs for downloading or open by a browser but not in the PDF Press preview mode.

More on that topic here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/pdf-press/viewthread/12549/P15